# How to read from an internal file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, file-io

I see a lot of questions online about how to read files in javascript on the local machine or how to read source from an external webpage, but what about just reading files from the internal webpage directory itself? It seems like this should be relatively simple, and shouldn't require server side script at all. But I can't seem to find a way to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: What is an internal webpage directory?

Comment: @ChrisHardie for example, if my index.html is at www.mywebpage.com, and I want to read a file from www.mywebpage.com/file.

Comment: How is the file internal if it resides on an external web server?

Comment: @ChrisHardie I'm pretty sure his desire is to read the file like you would with server side code, passing in a file path (e.g. `File.ReadAllText()` in C#), but with javascript, as opposed to making a web request to get the file contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do it would be the exact same way those questions regarding reading source from an external webpage are answered - using XmlHttpRequest in javascript, or something like $.ajax in jquery.

The important thing to remember is that javascript is not running on your server - it is running within the user's web browser. As such, it has no more access to the files on your server than any other code anywhere on the internet. You would need to make the file you want to read publicly accessible on your website and then make a web request via javascript to read the contents of the file and make use of it at that point.

Comment: Thanks. I am also guessing there isn't a way to have a purely script based <input type = "file"> that doesn't require a gui?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that - `<input type="file">` _is_ a GUI element.

Comment: Not sure what `<input type="file">` has to do with reading a file from the server hosting the website.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung I mean access local machine files through javascript or html alone, not with a gui (with a prompt that asks the user if its okay).

Comment: @WilliamOliver - No, you can't do that either, not without using something like Flash.